# Equation containing $\arcsin$ as well as square root.

Tags: physics, problem-solving

[image]

I was studying physics for an upcoming exam and found this in a practice sheet :

> A source S is oscillating between A and C with its position varying with time as $\displaystyle y (\text{in metres})=900\cos\frac{\pi}{6} t$. An observer situated at a distance $12$ m along the perpendicular bisector of. Frequency omitted by source is $300$ Hz. Approximate frequency observed by observer when sources at O is ____________. (Speed of sound in air=300 m/s)

> $A. 320 Hz \qquad B. 345 Hz \qquad C. 300 Hz \qquad D. 350 Hz$

So by the time S reaches O, the wave released by S at some point, say B, between C and O, reaches the observer. Now, I want to find the distance $OB=x$. Thus I will have the equation, equating the time taken by the sound (to reach observer) and S (to reach O):$$ \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+12^2}}{300}=\dfrac{\arcsin\left(\dfrac{x}{900}\right)}{2\pi}(\text{Time period})= \dfrac{\arcsin\left(\dfrac{x}{900}\right)}{2\pi}\dfrac{2\pi}{\frac{\pi}{6}}$$

If I find x, I’ll have no problem in solving the rest of the question.

How do I solve this? Or have I done it incorrectly?

Comment: Please provide source of the quesiton, thanks

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational done.

Comment: Hmm... I meant like if it came from specific exam or some question bank you own. This would help others who are interested find your question. It is clear already that it is physics and most probably from a practice sheet

Comment: It might help if you defined a coordinate system and wrote down an equation for B(t) and the source(t). My wild guess is that you're actually taking an arcsin of a cosine, and then a square root, which not only simplifies, but reduces to the Pythagorean Theorem

Comment: Is $y$ given to be in m or cm? If the answer given is C, it is very likely that $y$ is in fact in cm, and they expect you to ignore the movement of the source seeing as it's speed would be very negligible compared to sound.

Comment: @Cathedral I am sorry I forgot to mention that y is in meter. However, ans is still given as C.

Comment: The answer being given as C tells me that the exercise likely just wants you to calculate the frequency of the waves emitted by the source at point O (for a observed frequency equal to that of emitted frequency, the velocity of the source must be perpendicular to the line joining the observer and source). In any case, your exam is likely to be clearer.

Comment: Yeah @Cathedral thanks.